# iOS Packet Tunnel source vs destination modes and forms

Tags: ios, proxy, vpn, tunnel

I am trying to read and understand following paragraph from Apple docs.

> Packet tunnel providers can run in destination IP mode or source-application mode. The latter is one form of per-app VPN (the other form is an App Proxy Provider).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/packet_tunnel_provider

```
class NETunnelProvider
  An abstract base class shared by NEPacketTunnelProvider and NEAppProxyProvider.
```

So NEAppProxyProvider is not Packet Tunnel Provider. It is just Tunnel Provider.

Is there some mode (source mode) in NEPacketTunnelProvider that make it work like NEAppProxyProvider? How do I activate it?

Or ...  Is it just a mess of words in official Apple docs and they wished to say Tunnel Provider (not Packet Tunnel Provider) has two super-classes (modes): `PacketTunnerProvider` and `AppProxyProvider`

Why it is so important? Because NEAppProxyProvider works on managed devices only and PacketTunnerProvider works on all iOS9+ devices.

Comment: Using a per-app VPN, whether an application proxy, or packet tunnel in source mode requires that the device is managed and that a management payload is installed to specify which application bundle the VPN should apply to.